# unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.\n (chrome not reachable)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

After I install some dependencies in the `python:3.9` docker container:

```
RUN apt-get -y install chromium-driver
```

then I am using this code in Python 3 selenium to get some data:

```
    @staticmethod
    def fetch_music_download_url(music_name: str):
        chrome_driver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.GOOGLE).install())
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_driver_service,options=chrome_options)
        driver.get('http://tool.liumingye.cn/music/?page=audioPage&type=migu&name=' + music_name)
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".aplayer-list-download.iconfont.icon-xiazai").click()
        urls = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in
                driver.execute_script('return document.querySelectorAll(".modal-body a[href*=\'http\']")')]
        for url in urls:
            if url.contains("listenSong.do"):
                FetchMusic.do_save_music_download_url(url)
```

when I run this code in docker container. shows error:

```
Arguments: (WebDriverException('unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.\n  (chrome not reachable)\n  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)', None, ['#0 0x55a7c38fbee3 <unknown>', '#1 0x55a7c33c9608 <unknown>', '#2 0x55a7c33ec8ef <unknown>', '#3 0x55a7c33e846f <unknown>', '#4 0x55a7c3422f45 <unknown>', '#5 0x55a7c341d163 <unknown>', '#6 0x55a7c33f2bfc <unknown>', '#7 0x55a7c33f3c05 <unknown>', '#8 0x55a7c392dbaa <unknown>', '#9 0x55a7c3943651 <unknown>', '#10 0x55a7c392eb05 <unknown>', '#11 0x55a7c3944a68 <unknown>', '#12 0x55a7c392305f <unknown>', '#13 0x55a7c395f818 <unknown>', '#14 0x55a7c395f998 <unknown>', '#15 0x55a7c397aeed <unknown>', '#16 0x7fd8229b8ea7 <unknown>', '']),)
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to make it work?